# How to execute a Drupal-view in a custom module and print the output (as html-markup)?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-8

I want to print the output from a simple view in my custom module. But is doesnt work. I have tried many options from forums and stackoverflow. All of them print "array" instead of html-markup.

My controller:

```
class DefaultController extends ControllerBase {


    public function myfunc1() {

        $view = Views::getView('myfirstview');

        $view->setDisplay('page_1');
        $view->preExecute();
        $view->execute();

        // $myresults = $view->preview();  = array
        // $myresults = $view->render();  = array
        $myresults = $view->result; // = array


        return array(
            '#title' => 'Hello World!',
            '#markup' => $myresults,
        );
    }
}
```

How can I print the result/output of a view programmatically?

I dont want to make it without "embed view" , because I want to set some exposed filters later.

Answer (score 0):

get the view

```
$corresponding_view = Views::getView('myfirstview');
```

set exposed filters

```
$arguments = your arguments (exposed filter value);
$corresponding_view->setArguments($arguments);
```

embed your view

```
return [
  '#type' => 'view',
  '#name' => 'myfirstview',
  '#view' => $corresponding_view,
  '#display_id' => 'page_1',
  '#embed' => TRUE,
];
```

Comment: No - this results in an array to be rendered. It does not produce markup